# vk_api как отправить сообщения и в личные сообщения и в беседу?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

vk_api как отправить сообщения и в личные сообщения и в беседу?

Comment: Может, Вам нужен `peer_id`?

Comment: Дайте код...я так не понимаю что и куда вставлять, я новичок в vk_api